# How can I build a qa system to answer yes or no

Tags: python, prolog, nlp, nltk, nlp-question-answering

I would like to build a question answering system that it can answer only yes or no .

Suppose that I have got a question and a text file . In the text file , there are  4-5 snippets . With these snippets i could answer the question .

So , I would like to build a system that gets a question and a text file as input and extract an asnwer (yes or no)

How could I start ??

My tools are :
Python (nltk)
Prolog
mysql (if it needs )

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Something like this http://aclweb.org/anthology//C/C12/C12-1084.pdf ... User could ask questions for biomedical issues and my system would answer him , yes or no .

Answer (score 1):

Prolog itself is "a qa system to answer yes or no".

Your "text file" can be simple Prolog facts. Then you just load (consult) your facts file in Prolog system and use queries to get yes or no answers.

Example of top of my head (facts.pl):

```
prime(2).
prime(3).
prime(5).
prime(7).
capital('Ukraine', 'Kyiv').
capital('Ukraine', 'Kiev').
bird(penguin).
fish(shark).
```

Consult the file:

```
?- [facts].
```

Ask questions. Is penguin a bird? Is shark a bird?

```
?- bird(penguin).
true.
?- bird(shark).
false.
```

SWI-Prolog answers with 'true' and 'false', other systems (like ECLiPSe CLP http://www.eclipseclp.org/) may actually use 'Yes' and 'No'.

Comment: i know this !!

But , question and text file must be in natural language .

Thank you for your reply

Comment: @user3410338 Prolog excels at processing natural language.